# BeautifulSoup: Extract "img alt" content Web Scraping in Python

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am working in python 3. My objective is extracting differents values of one table and to put them in differents lists.

The problem is that i can't take the value of "img alt" in a td.

This is my code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

redditFile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.mtggoldfish.com/movers/online/all")
redditHtml = redditFile.read()
redditFile.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(redditHtml)
all_tables = soup.find_all('table')

right_table = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed movers-table')

#create a list
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]

for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    increment = row.findAll('span')
    colection = row.findAll('img')
    link = row.findAll('a')
    if len(cells) == 6:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(increment[0].find(text=True))
        C.append(colection[0])
        D.append(link[0].find(text=True))
print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)
```

This code gives me this result:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
['+8.40', '+2.47', '+1.35', '+1.28', '+1.14', '+0.99', '+0.94', '+0.91', '+0.90', '+0.75']
[<img alt="ORI" class="sprite-set_symbols_ORI" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-407aaa9c9786d606684c6967c47739c5.gif"/>, <img alt="PRM" class="sprite-set_symbols_PRM" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-407aaa9c9786d606684c6967c47739c5.gif"/>, <img alt="8ED" class="sprite-set_symbols_8ED" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-407aaa9c9786d606684c6967c47739c5.gif"/>, <img alt="EX" class="sprite-set_symbols_EX" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-407aaa9c9786d606684c6967c47739c5.gif"/>, <img alt="TSB" class="sprite-set_symbols_TSB" src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-407aaa9c9786d606684c6967c47739c5.gif"/>, <img alt="WL" class="sprite-set_symbols_WL"
```

src="//assets1.mtggoldfish.com/assets/s-407aaa9c9786d606684c6967c47739c5.gif"/>, , , , ]
    ["Jace, Vryn's Prodigy", "Gaea's Cradle", 'Ensnaring Bridge', 'City of Traitors', 'Pendelhaven', 'Firestorm', 'Kor Spiritdancer', 'Scalding Tarn', 'Daybreak Coronet', 'Grove of the Burnwillows']

But I need the IMG ALT VALUE in (for exemple the first img alt value is "ORI")

> colection variable

**I don't have any idea that I can do. Guys, could you help me with this, please?**

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the alt's from the img tags, you just need to select the img tags from the table and extract the alt attributes:

```
right_table = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed movers-table')

print([img["alt"] for img in right_table.select("img[alt]")])
['ORI', 'PRM', '8ED', 'EX', 'TSB', 'WL', 'ROE', 'ZEN', 'FUT', 'FUT']
```

In your own loop you are using findAll when you seem to want only one element, if you only want the first then use find `row.find('span')` etc.. and `row.find('img')["alt"]` will give you the alt value for each row, looking at the page there is only one per tr so you definitely don't need findAll.

If you want to recreate the table locally I would put the data in a dict:

```
right_table = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed movers-table')


table_dict = {}

for row in right_table.select("tr"):
    # increase class are where increments are 
    increments = [s.text for s in row.select('span.increase')]
    # make sure we have some data in tr
    if increments:
        # rank/place is first text in td, could also use find("td",{"class":"first-right"})
        place = int(row.td.text) 
        # text/character name is in a tag text
        title = row.find("a").text
        increments.append(title)
       # get alt attribute from img tag
        increments.append(row.find("img")["alt"])
        table_dict[place] = increments

from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(table_dict)
```

Output:

```
{1: [u'+8.78', u'68.03', u'+15.00%', u"Jace, Vryn's Prodigy", 'ORI'],
 2: [u'+2.47', u'47.96', u'+5.00%', u"Gaea's Cradle", 'PRM'],
 3: [u'+1.95', u'20.37', u'+11.00%', u'Firestorm', 'WL'],
 4: [u'+1.73', u'23.91', u'+8.00%', u'Force of Will', 'VMA'],
 5: [u'+1.35', u'40.88', u'+3.00%', u'Ensnaring Bridge', '8ED'],
 6: [u'+1.28', u'44.02', u'+3.00%', u'City of Traitors', 'EX'],
 7: [u'+1.15', u'41.98', u'+3.00%', u'Time Walk', 'VMA'],
 8: [u'+1.01', u'28.68', u'+4.00%', u'Daze', 'NE'],
 9: [u'+1.01', u'19.96', u'+5.00%', u"Goryo's Vengeance", 'BOK'],
 10: [u'+1.00', u'3.99', u'+33.00%', u'Unearth', 'UL']}
```

Which you will see matches the current table data exactly, also if you want all the winners just change the url to `http://www.mtggoldfish.com/movers-details/online/all/winners/dod`

Or if you want to break the fields up and just pull the firs increment:

```
for row in right_table.select("tr"):
    increment = row.find('span',{"class":'increase'})
    if increment:
        increment = increment.text
        place = int(row.td.text)
        title = row.select("a[data-full-image]")[0].text
        alt = (row.find("img")["alt"])
        table_dict[place] = {"title":title,"alt":alt, "inc":increment}


from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(table_dict)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'alt': 'ORI', 'inc': u'+8.78', 'title': u"Jace, Vryn's Prodigy"},
 2: {'alt': 'PRM', 'inc': u'+2.47', 'title': u"Gaea's Cradle"},
 3: {'alt': 'WL', 'inc': u'+1.95', 'title': u'Firestorm'},
 4: {'alt': 'VMA', 'inc': u'+1.73', 'title': u'Force of Will'},
 5: {'alt': '8ED', 'inc': u'+1.35', 'title': u'Ensnaring Bridge'},
 6: {'alt': 'EX', 'inc': u'+1.28', 'title': u'City of Traitors'},
 7: {'alt': 'VMA', 'inc': u'+1.15', 'title': u'Time Walk'},
 8: {'alt': 'NE', 'inc': u'+1.01', 'title': u'Daze'},
 9: {'alt': 'BOK', 'inc': u'+1.01', 'title': u"Goryo's Vengeance"},
 10: {'alt': 'UL', 'inc': u'+1.00', 'title': u'Unearth'}}
```

Comment: Padraic, thanks for your support! your print works very well. But my problem is when i want put this value in my variable (colection = row.find('img')["alt"] ) it shows me this error  colection = row.find('img')["alt"]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

thanks a lot for your explanation.

Comment: @CarlosRocaPin, If you use the code above exactly as it is you will get all the data you need. I forgot to add the alt's but they are there now with the edit

Comment: Padric just now i read your last answer . THANKS So much!!!! Works perfect! I will stud the code .

THANKS!!!! Muchas Gracias!!!!

Comment: @CarlosRocaPin, no prob, you're welcome, I added a few comments that should hopefully help.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have an `<img>` node instance, you can get the alt value using this:

```
alt_tag = img.attrs['alt']
```

Since you're getting a collection of img elements, you can iterate over it and retrieve the alt tag for each:

```
tags = []
collection = soup.findAll("img")
for img in collection:
    if 'alt' in img.attrs:
        tags.append(img.attrs['alt'])
#do whatever you need to do with your list of alt attributes.
print tags
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

Thanks for your answer !!!  but i dont now why .. show my this error..
line 27, in <module>

    tags.append(img.attrs['alt'])

KeyError: 'alt'    thanks again!!

Comment: A key error occurs when you're using a Python dictionary (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and try to access an element that hasn't been defined within the dictionary yet. Since the alt attribute isn't required, you should confirm that it is set on the <img> element before trying to access it. Edited my answer to show this check.